# selected value in multiselect combobox in extjs

Tags: javascript, checkbox, extjs, combobox, multi-select

in my code :

```
multiSelect: true,
tpl: new Ext.XTemplate('<tpl for=".">', '<div class="x-boundlist-item">', '<input type="checkbox" />', '{errorCode}', " ", '{errorDesc}', '</div>', '</tpl>'),

listeners: {
   select: function(combo, records) {
     var node;
     debugger;
     Ext.each(records, function(rec) {
       node = combo.getPicker().getNode(rec);
       Ext.get(node).down('input').dom.checked = true;
     });
   },
   beforedeselect: function(combo, rec) {
     var node = combo.getPicker().getNode(rec);
     Ext.get(node).down('input').dom.checked = false;
   },
```

I have a multi-select `combobox` with a checkbox beside it for checking,it works well for selecting and deselecting, but when combo expands it doesn't show checked items at firstmafter another selecting or deselecting it will work!but I need to check selected item when user open the combo!

thanks.

Comment: can u please create fiddle using https://fiddle.sencha.com/ with detailed code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added an expand listener and my problem is solved:

```
 expand: function(combo) {
     var node;
     Ext.each(combo.pickerSelectionModel.selected.items, function(rec) {
         node = combo.getPicker().getNode(rec);
         Ext.get(node).down('input').dom.checked = true;
     });
 }
```